Why its proving Angles Add: Arg(wz) = Arg(w) + Arg(z) using ODEs, and how its expanding Exponential Law that way?
The material I'm reading goes this way:
First introduced this,

(11)  Magnitudes Multiply: |wz| = |w||z|

Which is easy to prove using Euler' formula
Then its introduced to "to understand what happens to arguments we have to think about the product exp(r)exp(s)", and I think he is expanding Exponential Law into the complex world.

(12)  For any complex numbers r and s, exp(r+s) = exp(r)exp(s)

It says "this fact comes out of the uniqueness of ODEs", which I don't know why he's saying it and why then "put t into the picture". The final work was meant to prove this:

(15) Angles Add: Arg(wz) = Arg(w) + Arg(z)

Which can then be used to find Roots of Numbers.
Please help me understand all these processes.
Source(start from page 32, 6.4. Multiplication): https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/18-03-differential-equations-spring-2010/a3c8b903c3e2e37427d8860d1cbebb5e_MIT18_03S10_chapter_6.pdf

If it is said "using ODE = Ordinary Differential Equations", it means that you start by considering diff. equation $y'=biy$ with $y(0)=\exp(a)$ ($a$ being a real constant) ) whose solution is $y(t)=y(0)\exp(bit)=\exp(a+bit)$ then take $t=1$, etc.

If the source you're considering is available, it would be helpful to include a link in the question body.
